# RaspberryPi SD card unusable after taking an image with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: raspberrypi, sd-card

I have a Raspberrypi 4 8Gb installed with Ubuntu 21.04, using the Raspberrypi imager, on a Sandisk Ultra microSD card 128Gb. After sometime, the Raspberrypi would 'randomly' not boot up, leaving a black screen. In an attempt to save the SD card setup, I researched how to create an image of the SD card by using the 'dd' command in Ubuntu 20.04. This image was then written to a new SD card (exact same type). However the Raspberrypi would not boot on the new SD card AND the original SD card.

I did extensive online research to find ways to recover the SD cards (at least the new one) through formatting, re-partioning, etc but was unsuccessful. It seemed from what I could find online that I did not unmouted the SD card before starting the image, which corrupted the SD card and/or the image. Eventually I resorted to buying another new SD card and rebuilding the system. Once successfully setup, I decided create another image of the new-new SD card (after unmounting the drive) for 'safe keeping'. Creating the image was done on a Virtualbox VM running Ubuntu 20.04.

Unfortunately the same result, an unusable SD card (see screen pic attached).

Please help:

1. Are the SD cards recoverable? How?
2. How can images be made without corrupting the card/image?

[Boot error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UE9dG.jpg)

Comment: Is your goal to use sd card again after it has been used for pi purpose?

Comment: The first goal is to get the cd card working in the pi again, without starting with another new card and a fresh install. The other goal is to have one sd card 'working' in the pi and then a spare sd card with an image of the working card as a backup